# How to use "Get Contents" API on Github to dump contents of a file to another file

Tags: shell, github, github-api

noob question here but I am trying to use https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents (GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path) to retrieve the contents of a file in github. If I wanted to dump the contents of this repo/file for example (https://github.com/ravahn/FFXIV_ACT_Plugin/blob/master/Releases/FFXIV_ACT_Plugin_1.2.3.1.zip), what would be the correct shell command? In addition, how could I input a GHE token if it was a private repo/file?